# Nginx user restriction checked with cookies

Tags: nginx, web, nginx-config

I'm working on a little PHP Service on my webserver for my clients. The concept is simple:

I'm making a website for a client of mine locally. I upload it onto my publicly accesible webserver. Now I don't want anybody to have access onto every website. So I made a login form (via password) with php and html. The userdata is saved in a MySQL Database.

So if a user gets the url of me (e.g. client.raphaelbernhart.at) there is a input field with a password to be filled out. Now if the user submits the password the php script checks is there is a user with this password and creates a session and cookie.

As the information (client websites) are most of the time not very sensitive I wanted to proof with the nginx configuration if a cookie is created at the clients computer and if the path (url) contains the username specified inside the cookie. My configuration for something like this would be:

```
location /client {

        # Check if url contains auth cookie value
        if ($request_uri != $cookie_auth){
                return 401;
        }

    }
```

But this isn't working...

It would be greate if anybody could help me with this problem...thanks

Also I want to check if there is a administrator cookie created and then always send status 200.

Something like this:

```
# Check if url contains auth cookie value
        if ($cookie_auth = "administrator"){
                return 200;
        }
```

But this isn't working to.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
location /client {
    set $deny 1;
    if ($uri ~ ^/client/$cookie_auth) {
        set $deny '';
    }
    if ($cookie_auth = administrator) {
        set $deny '';
    }
    if ($cookie_auth = '') {
        set $deny 1;
    }
    if ($deny) {
        return 401;
    }
    ... # further processing
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
The
'''if ($cookie_auth = administrator) {
        set $deny '';
    }''' config is working fine but the 
'''if ($uri ~ ^/client/$cookie_auth/) {
        set $deny '';
    }''' isn't working...

Comment: @dizon27 How do you check it? `/client/username/` should work, `/client/username` would not. If you change regex from `^/client/$cookie_auth/` to `^/client/$cookie_auth` it will allow any access when the `auth` cookie doesn't set at all.

Comment: I've tryed every possible solution now. If I do: '''return 200 /client/$cookie_auth''' I get back "/client/THECLIENTUSERNAME". If I do '''return 200 $uri''' I get back "/client/THECLIENTUSERNAME" so they are the same but I don't know whats the problem :/

Comment: @dizon27 You shouldn't use `return 200 "something"` at all, it won't do what you expected, it would just return `"something"` as a response to request. If you want to use `/client/username` request instead of `/client/username/`, try the updated answer.

Comment: The map directive would be much more efficient here